# pandas row filtering with condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

My pandas dataframe looks like following:

```
>df
          time           w_m       w_s       p_m       p_s
0            1  43102.490062  0.935265  0.000000  0.416194
1            2  41692.002871  0.942409  0.000000  0.416208
2            3  40592.822117  0.956229  0.000000  0.416222
3            4  40218.101405  0.956392  0.000000  0.416236
4            5  39606.057576  0.958667  0.000000  0.416250
5            6  37483.601032  0.961907  0.000000  0.416264
6            7  37678.647967  0.965330  0.000000  0.416278
7            8  38082.193349  0.965330  0.000000  0.416292
```

I would like to filter my data frame so that only the rows, which have`'_m'` at the end of their headers name.

Following output is what I desire to accomplish via `a = df.some_method()`:

```
>a

             w_m       p_m
0   43102.490062  0.000000 
1   41692.002871  0.000000
2   40592.822117  0.000000
3   40218.101405  0.000000
4   39606.057576  0.000000
5   37483.601032  0.000000
6   37678.647967  0.000000
7   38082.193349  0.000000
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with parameter `regex` and `^` for match start of string, or `$` for match end of string:

```
print (df)
   time           w_m     _mw_s  p_m     _mp_s
0     1  43102.490062  0.935265  0.0  0.416194
1     2  41692.002871  0.942409  0.0  0.416208
2     3  40592.822117  0.956229  0.0  0.416222
3     4  40218.101405  0.956392  0.0  0.416236
4     5  39606.057576  0.958667  0.0  0.416250
5     6  37483.601032  0.961907  0.0  0.416264
6     7  37678.647967  0.965330  0.0  0.416278
7     8  38082.193349  0.965330  0.0  0.416292
```

---

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^_m')
print (df1)
      _mw_s     _mp_s
0  0.935265  0.416194
1  0.942409  0.416208
2  0.956229  0.416222
3  0.956392  0.416236
4  0.958667  0.416250
5  0.961907  0.416264
6  0.965330  0.416278
7  0.965330  0.416292

df2 = df.filter(regex='_m$')
print (df2)
            w_m  p_m
0  43102.490062  0.0
1  41692.002871  0.0
2  40592.822117  0.0
3  40218.101405  0.0
4  39606.057576  0.0
5  37483.601032  0.0
6  37678.647967  0.0
7  38082.193349  0.0
```

If want all values `_m` use parameter `like`:

```
df3 = df.filter(like='_m')
print (df3)
            w_m     _mw_s  p_m     _mp_s
0  43102.490062  0.935265  0.0  0.416194
1  41692.002871  0.942409  0.0  0.416208
2  40592.822117  0.956229  0.0  0.416222
3  40218.101405  0.956392  0.0  0.416236
4  39606.057576  0.958667  0.0  0.416250
5  37483.601032  0.961907  0.0  0.416264
6  37678.647967  0.965330  0.0  0.416278
7  38082.193349  0.965330  0.0  0.416292
```

Comment: it works, but it would also filter if `'_m'` is at the beginning, is there anyway to force `filter()` to check specific point of the header?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
a = df.iloc[:,df.columns.str.contains('_m$')]

print(a)
            w_m  p_m
0  43102.490062  0.0
1  41692.002871  0.0
2  40592.822117  0.0
3  40218.101405  0.0
4  39606.057576  0.0
5  37483.601032  0.0
6  37678.647967  0.0
7  38082.193349  0.0
```

**Explanation :**

1. If you want to check `_m` at the end of name use `_m$` as regex
2. If you want to check `_m` at the start of name use `^_m` as regex
3. If you want to just check whether contains `_m` use `_m` as regex.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension solution:

```
df_new = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.endswith('_m')]]
```